# How to secure firebase google-services.json file while reverse engineering

Tags: android, firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, reverse-engineering

I am using Firebase realtime database in my application. Recently my application was hacked and some other application is also reading data from my Firebase database.

My app has been reverse engineered and all api keys in google-services.json file are stolen and being used.

Now how can I secure my application?

Comment: The data that Firebase takes from your google-services.json and puts in the APK is not secret, but merely configuration information to find your Firebase project on Google's servers. To protect your back-end services against abuse you'd use Firebase Authentication and server-side security rules. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public